# write to json file possible?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a html file as follows to enter details of user, when i press submit it should go to a file created my myself(myfile.json)which is empty now.

please provide code for that.

```
   <ion-view view-title="employee">
     <ion-content>

      <!-- <input type="date" id=FromDate" name="FromDate"  ng-model="FromDate" date-format="yyyy-MM-dd"/> -->

     <form name="formname" ng-submit="logdata(formname)">
  <h1 >{{data.FromDate|date}}</h1>

     <label class="item item-input ">
<div class="input-label">date:</div>
  <input type="date" name="name" value="" ng-model="data.FromDate"></input>
   </label>
        <div class="list">





        </div>
       <div class="list">

          <label class="item item-input item-select">
         <div class="input-label">
        Project
      </div>
      <select ng-options="project.name as project.name for project in projects" ng-model="data.selectedProject">
        <!-- <option>createwhimsy</option>
       <option selected>activity tracker</option>
        <option>big iron</option> -->
      </select>
    </label>

  </div>
  <div class="list">

    <label class="item item-input item-select">
      <div class="input-label">
        Manager
      </div>
      <select ng-model="data.manager">

        <option selected>deepa</option>

      </select>
    </label>

  </div>
  <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label">task</span>

         <textarea placeholder="task details goes here" rows="8" cols="10" ng-model="data.task"></textarea>
  </label>

      <div class="list">

    <label class="item item-input item-select">
      <div class="input-label">
        Estimated time(hrs)
      </div>
       <select ng-model="data.time">

        <option selected>1</option>
        <option selected>2</option>
        <option selected>3</option>
        <option selected>4</option>
        <option selected>5</option>
        <option selected>6</option>

      </select>
    </label>

  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="button button-calm">
    submit
  </button>
    </form>

  </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
```

possible, need simple code, in controller.with pure angularjs.

Comment: Hi, what have you tried?

Comment: Search for **"ionic write to file"** will give you the answer with many examples.

Comment: i have a data object named data, i can log it, can i post to that file using http.post?